# How to run the demo vaadin dashboard-demo in eclipse

Tags: vaadin

How to run the demo vaadin dashboard-demo in eclipse. I've downloaded their project from github?
https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo.git

I am using eclipse version juno wtp

Comment: did you try to run it on a tomcat server?

Answer (score 2):

1. Download zip (https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo)
2. Extract dashboard-demo-master.zip
3. Eclipse: File-> Import-> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects (click next)
4. For root Directory: browse "dashboard-demo-master" directory with pom.xml (click finish)
5. Right click on eclipse project "quicktickets-dashboard" run as-> maven install
6. After download of sources Run As-> Run on server

Comment: After the 4th step, I get two errors: No marketplace entries found to handle vaadin-maven-plugin:7.3.8:compile-theme in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information. AND No marketplace entries found to handle vaadin-maven-plugin:7.3.8:update-theme in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information. Why? Can I solve them?

Answer (score 1):

https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/2489264?_19_delta=20&_19_keywords=&_19_advancedSearch=false&_19_andOperator=true&cur=1

here blog about this QuickTickets Demo Sources